# Прижать к низу страницы FLOAT-элемент

Tags: html, css

имеется вёрстка подобного плана

> ```
> <div class="upper"></div>
> <div class="main">
>   <div class="column1"></div>
>   <div class="column2"></div>
> </div>
> <div class="footer"></div>
> ```

как сделать, чтобы футер прижимался к низу при отсутствии достаточного контента в колонках и при этом, естественно, при его достатке сдвигался вниз?

НЕТ, В ГУГЛЕ Я НИЧЕГО НЕ НАШЁЛ НА ТЕМУ ФЛОАТОВ. есть варианты прижатия, но нигде не используются флоаты. а они мне жизненно необходимы.

ответ "не юзай флоаты" не принимается.

Comment: хотя бы стили напишите..

Comment: там ничего особенного нету.
из необходимого - все элементы, кроме column2 имеют float: left; (у второй колонки - float: right;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы это работало с doctype, т.е. в режиме Standards Mode, необходимо, чтобы высота, заданая в процентах была у элементов по цепочке, начиная с html -> body и т.д. Т.е. по умолчанию в этих элементах высота находится в значении auto, что в Вашем случае не дает возможности задать её в процентах для других элементов
   Т.е. для кода выше, без задания этого:

```
 html, body {
    height: 100%;}
```

Вы не сможете задать для элемента с классом page-wrapper высоту в 100%

Comment: Во, спасибо большое! у меня в боди стоял min-height вместо height :) сейчас вроде бы всё ок)

Answer (score 1):

[Как прижать подвал к низу страницы](http://www.zakharov.ms/footer/).

Элементарно просто и отлично работает, советую посмотреть всем кто использует `position`

```
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">

<div class="page-buffer"></div>
</div>
<div class="page-footer">

</div>
</body>
```

Внутри `.page-wrapper` можете использовать float и прочее

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.page-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
* html .page-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
.page-buffer {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Не могу понять, почему, но этот способ работает, только если удалить из кода ДОКТАЙП о_О
при доктайпе "враппер" считается пустым, и захваченные флоат-элементе в него будто бы не входят. И соответственно при отрицательном отступе получается сдвиг всего сайта целиком вверх.

Answer (score 0):

[тут](http://css-tricks.ru/Articles/Details/AllAboutFloats) нет ничего полезного?

Comment: Здесь нет ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: @Garfild, вам @Dazar уже написал в комментарии, что не мешало бы стили ваши показать. Или нам просто догадаться надо?